# Pymongo calling `insert_one` without checking the keys

Tags: python, pymongo

`MongoDB` supports now documents with keys having special characters such as `.` or `$` (at the beginning). My code does some insertions using `insert_one` mostly, with `pymongo-3.7.1` and `mongodb-4.1.1`, and my keys do contain some `.`. The problem is that this raises:

```
InvalidDocument: key '13213.123123' must not contain '.'
```

I can make the insertion happen by using `collection.insert` with `check_keys=False` instead of `collection.insert_one` but I then get a `DeprecationWarning`. Is there a way to for the insertion with `insert_one`, and maybe `insert_many`?

I have tried `bypass_document_validation=True` but it raises `InvalidDocument` again.

Comment: Currently I'm using `insert(doc, check_keys=False)` instead of `insert_one`. I know `insert` it's deprecated, but it works fine with one doc